# Python compare exif thumbnail with original image

Tags: python, image, exif

I'm currently writing an extractor for exif data in python. One of the features I want to implement is to cross check if there are missmatches between the exif stored thumbnail and the original image to detect if someone edited the image. Here is what I have:

```
#import packages
import exifread
f = open('examplepics/0R2A0584.jpg', 'rb')
print(f)
#print(f.read())
tags = exifread.process_file((f))
thumb_val = None
for k,v in tags.items():
    print("key: " + str(k) + " | value: " + str(v))
    if k == 'JPEGThumbnail':
        thumb_val = v

original_val = f.read()
if thumb_val == original_val:
    print("Same value!")
else:
    print("different!")
```

Currently it prints "different!" which is wrong since the picture was not edited in any way.
I'm also quite new to the whole exif topic so I'm a little bit stuck here. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `f.read()` return? Probably nothing?

Comment: Hi, it returns the binary information (b'\xff\xd8\xff\xdb\x00\x84\x00\x06....)  but it is not the same as the exif thumbnail binary information :-/ (but it must be the same since the picture was not edited

Comment: But why do you expect it to return the same information? Does `exifread.process_file` rewind the filehandle after reading from it?

Comment: I thought (but maybe I'm wrong) that the thumbnail image in exif basically stores the same information as the original image and assumed that both binary values should be the same.

Comment: That would seem like a weird design. Surely the data only has to be stored once. I would expect the thumbnail to contain fewer pixels, each sampling or approximating the contents of a region in the larger image.

Comment: But also, you have already consumed part of the file; do you expect the file pointer to be at the beginning of the original image?

Comment: And also, compressed image data can easily be different even if it represents the same image as another set of compressed image data.

Comment: Hmm yeah you got a point here. In some naive way I thought that it somehow could store the same information. Sorry but I think it is clear to me now, that there isn't an easy solution to this, thanks!